# Finding the key with maximum value in a PCollection of key-value pairs

Tags: apache-beam

I have a `PCollection` of `KV<String,Integer>` items, and I want to find the pair in which the value is largest.

For example, if the key-value pairs were 
`{foo:3,bar:2,baz:7}`
then the result would be a single pair `baz:7`.

None of the methods in the [Max class](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/0.3.0-incubating/org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Max.html) seem to do exactly what I want:

- `Max.integersPerKey` gives a `PCollection` of key-value pairs of the highest value associated with each key in the input; I just want a single item with the globally highest value.
- `Max.integersGlobally` requires a `PCollection` of Integers; it doesn't take key-value pairs. Mapping from the KV pairs to just the values then using this would give the highest value, but I'd also like to preserve the key associated with that value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should work when you use `Max.of(comparator)` and implement a comparator which compares the value of your `KV<String,Integer>`.

Such a comparator can look as follows:

```
 public static class KVComparator implements Comparator<KV<String,Integer>>, Serializable {
        @Override
        public int compare(KV<String, Integer> o1, KV<String, Integer> o2) {
         return   o1.getValue().compareTo(o2.getValue());
        }
    }
```

When you have a `PCollection<KV<String,Integer>>`  `p` it then looks like that:

```
 p.apply(Combine.globally(Max.of(new KVComparator())));
```